# react-native : How to render check box inside flatlist

Tags: javascript, react-native

I created a `checkbox` inside my flatlist but when I click on the checkbox all the check boxes will render. I want to render the checkbox I press not the entire checkboxes.

This is my code:

```
const list = [
  {
    name: 'Kevin',
    id:0
  },
  {
    name: 'John',
    id:1
  },
]
export default class TestingScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      checked: false
    }
  }

  handleCheckBox = () => this.setState({ checked: !this.state.checked })

  renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <ListItem
      title={<View><Text>{item.name}</Text></View>}r
      leftAvatar={
        <View>
        <Image
                  style={{width:50, height:50,borderRadius:25 }}
                  source={require('../Components/Assets/oval.png')} />
        </View>
      }
      rightAvatar={
        <CheckBox
          checked={this.state.checked}
          onPress={() => this.setState({checked: !this.state.checked})}
        />
      }
    >
    </ListItem>

  )

  render() {
  return(
    <View style={styles.container}>
    <FlatList
         keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
         data={list}
         renderItem={this.renderItem}
         extraData={this.state}
       />
      </View>
    )
  };
}
```

Is there a way I could just render the checkbox I pressed? 
Any comments or advise would be really helpful thanks! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the same state variable for all your checkboxes. Clicking on one of the checkboxs will update the single global variable `checked` you gave to all checkboxes.

You have to either create a checkBox component with his own state or update a variable inside the list you are using to render the different items.

For example:

1)Move your list variable inside the state adding a checked key:

```
const list = [
  {
    name: 'Kevin',
    id:0,
    checked:false
  },
  {
    name: 'John',
    id:1,
    checked:false
  },
] 



 this.state = {
  list: list
}
```

2) Use the state into the flatList data:

```
<FlatList
     keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
     data={this.state.list}
     renderItem={this.renderItem}
     extraData={this.state}
/>
```

3) Change the onPress of the checkBox:

```
<CheckBox
      checked={this.state.list[item.id].checked}
      onPress={() => this.checkThisBox(item.id)}
    />
```

where:

```
checkThisBox=(itemID)=>{
   let list=this.state.list
   list[itemID].checked=!list[itemID].checked
   this.setState({list:list})
}
```

Comment: what if the data is dynamic and it is not having checked field which you are using for the validation.?

Answer (score 1):

save the `item.id` in the state when triggering `onPress`

Example :

```
this.state = {
    checked : null
}
```

then in your checkbox :

```
<CheckBox
  checked={this.state.checked === item.id}
  onPress={() => this.setState({checked: item.id})}
/>
```

**OR**

you can do it like

```
this.state = {
  list: list,
},
```

then in your `flatlist`

```
          <FlatList
              keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
              data={this.state.list}
              renderItem={({item, index}) =>

                  <ListItem>
                      <Left>
                          <Text>{item.name}</Text>
                      </Left>
                      <Right>
                            <CheckBox
                              checked={item.checked}
                              onPress={() => this.onCheck(item,index)}
                            />
                      </Right>
                  </ListItem>

              }
              extraData={this.state}
          />
```

oncheck function

```
onCheck = (item, i) => {
      let items = this.state.list;
      items[i].checked = items[i].checked ? ! items[i].checked : true
      this.setState({list:items})

    }
```